# Showing density of something in 2d spacematlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have three 1 by n vectors: x, y and phi. 
x and y determine a position in 2D space and phi(i) is amount of particles exist in position(x(i),y(i)). I want to plot 2d region which shows the amount of particles in space with colors. for example, positions in which particles are concentrated be different from positions with the smaller amount of particles. 
Could anyone help me how can I do that? Any answers are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
%assuming your x,y locations are positive (otherwise simply shift)
S = max( max(x), max(y) );
MAP = zeros(S,S);

for particle = 1:n
    MAP( x(particle ), y(particle ) ) = MAP( x(particle ), y(particle ) ) + 1;
end

%then you can surf the MAP
```

Plot MAP using surf or even imshow. [Surf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) is probably what you are looking for!

Comment: How can I Fill the values phi(i) on the diagonal of MAP?

Comment: There is a problem in using your method. This is my code: MAP(1:nmolecules,1:nmolecules)=min(phi)-1;
   MAP(eye(size(MAP))~=0)=phi;
    surf(x,y,MAP)
    scatter(xm,ym, [], dens,'filled','d')
    drawnow

Comment: xm and ym are the position of other particles which I want to show them also.

Comment: Let me edit my answer, I think you mean something more general.

Comment: should it be MAP( x(n), y(n) ) or MAP( x(particle), y(particle) )?

Comment: x and y are not integer numbers

Comment: I need 2d plot not three D.

Comment: If you used surf then to see it in 2D right click on the figure and pick the {x-y view}, it is in 2D but the third dimension that you are seeing is proportional to the number of particles, in 2D view it will be transformed to color intensity.

Comment: there is an error in MAP( x(particle ), y(particle ) ) . because x(particle) and y(particle) are not integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scatter(x,y,phi)
```

or

```
scatter(x,y,[],phi)
```

If you want to modify circle colors instead of circle sizes.